# How to iterate HashMap without entrySet

Tags: java

In original java source, i must use entrySet to iterate a hashmap, for instance:

```
 for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : new Hash<String, String>().entrySet()) {
 }
```

I expect a more simple way to iterate a hashmap like following:

```
package ro.ex;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class Hash<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {
    // how to implement?
}

public class Ex2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // i expect

        for (Hash.Entry<String, String > e : new Hash<String, String>()) {
        }
    }
}
```

**my question is** how to implement it?

Comment: entryset is not the only way to iterate through a Map... you can use the keySet, values, or get an interator of the keys etc.

Comment: By "more simple way" you mean "without typing `.entrySet()`"?

Answer (score 2):

Implement `Iterable<Map.Entry<K, V>>`:

```
class Hash<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> implements Iterable<Map.Entry<K, V>> {
    @Override
    public Iterator<Entry<K, V>> iterator() {
        return entrySet().iterator();
    }
}
```

This works because implementing [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) allows the type to be used in a for-each loop.

Answer (score 2):

As a supplement to @August's answer, while it is not difficult to make a `Map` directly iterable like that, it is also *not a good idea*.

- You've introduced a new `Hash` class that provides no substantial new functionality.  It is really just a convenience class.  Extra classes means more classes to read<sup>1</sup> and maintain and a larger runtime footprint.
- In order to use your `Hash` class, your other code needs to code to the `Hash` class rather than the `Map` interface.  This makes it impossible to directly replace the map with a different `Map` implementation type.
- Your `Hash` class is arguably unintuitive.  There are three (at least) aspects of a `Map` that could be iterated, but you chosen one ... for reasons that are not generally obvious.  (That's why the standard `Map` API does not implement `Iterable` !!)
- When you define a subclass of `HashMap`, you prevent the JIT compiler from optimizing away the dispatching on certain method calls in certain situations.

Now none of these things is a "show stopper" ... but on the other hand, all you have achieved is to save ~10 characters in the `for` loop.

---

<sup>1 - This may not be a problem for you as the original author.  But someone else encountering your `Hash` class for the first time would have to go read the source code or javadoc to figure out what iterating it really means ...</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Java 8, the best and easiest way to iterate the HashMap is by making use of the Lambda expression. Below is the code snippet to [iterate HashMap](https://www.myjavacode.com/iterate-java-hashmap/) ,

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>(); 

map.put("Robert", 34);
map.put("Kiran", 29);
map.put("Andy", 44);

map.forEach((key,value) -> {
System.out.println(key);
System.out.println(value);});
```